# Selective revert on locally modified files

Tags: svn

When reverting files that have been modified locally, is there a way to exclude files? Due to circumstances beyond my control, my current workflow is to:

1. Create a diff of files I want to include
2. svn status to get a list of modifications
3. svn revert, copypasting the files that were included in the diff
4. rm'ing leftovers - i.e. added files not under version control

What I'm after would look something like

```
svn revert -R --exclude file1 --exclude file2 /my/path
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [changelists](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.changelists.html).

Tag all files as `to_revert`:
  `$ svn changelist to_revert -R /my/path`

Untag some files:
`$ svn changelist --remove file1 file2`

Revert only tagged files:
`$ svn revert --changelist to_revert -R /my/path`

Comment: This is preferable but, afaik, overwrites files in other changelists.

Comment: It destroys any changelists you have, true. Maybe you could put the files you want to exclude in a changelist instead, and rather that reverting the rest just use the --cl argument with commits etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` to do the matching.

```
find . -name .svn -prune -o -name file1 -o -name file2 -o -print0 |
    xargs -0 svn revert --
```

- `-name file1` excludes by file name in any subdirectory,
- `-path ./src/file1` excludes by specific path,
- `-path ./src/dir1 -prune` excludes an entire directory.